# How do I diagnose Xcode message “Linker command failed with exit code 1”?

Tags: c, xcode

I am trying to teach myself some C, and I am stuck almost right off the bat in xCode.  Currently I have a folder structure that looks like this:

[image]

main.c looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int dogs;

    printf("How many dogs do you have?\n");
    scanf("%d", &dogs);
    printf("So you have %d dog(s)! \n", dogs);

    return 0;
}
```

concrete.c looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("Concrete contains gravel and cement.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

No matter which one I run via Product->Run I get the same error:

[image]

Any ideas what is causing this?  Coming from Python background only so these errors and xCode in general are totally new to me

EDIT- deleting the concrete.c file fixed the issue, but that doesn't seem reasonable to me.  Is that because I had 2 files with int main(void) in it?

Comment: You should not have two definitions of `main`. `main` is the name for the unique routine that is called to start your program.

Comment: @EricPostpischil thanks, so even though they were in separate files it doesn't matter?  Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: By default, in C, function names have external linkage, meaning the same name in different translation units (source files, when used normally) refer to the same thing. So there cannot be two functions with the same name—any name, not just `main`—because then you have two things with the same name. You can give a function internal linkage instead of external by declaring it with `static`, and then that name will not conflict with the same name in other translation units.

Comment: @EricPostpischil thanks!  So if I am following along in a book and I want to create different folders/files for each chapter I should name the functions differently in each file just to be safe or just use static as you said.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You should write a proper answer with that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on Xcode’s display of “Linker command failed with exit code 1”, it should show you the portion of the build log where the linker is displaying messages and exiting with code 1.

These messages include:

```
duplicate symbol _main in:
[Some path on your system…]/Build/Intermediates.noindex/foo.build/Debug/foo.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/foo.o
[Some path on your system…]/Build/Intermediates.noindex/foo.build/Debug/foo.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

That message “duplicate symbol _main” tells you the problem: You have two definitions of `main`. `main` is the name for the unique routine that is called to start your program, and you should have only one definition for it.

### Supplement

By default, in C, function names have external linkage, meaning the same name in different translation units (source files, when used normally) refer to the same thing. So there cannot be two functions with the same name—any name, not just `main`—because then you have two things with the same name. You can give a function internal linkage instead of external by declaring it with static, and then that name will not conflict with the same name in other translation units.

Nonetheless, defining a `static` version of `main` may result in compiler complaints, both that `main` should not be declared with `static` and that it ought to be declared to return `int`, if you declared it otherwise. These stem from text in the C standard, at C 2018 5.1.2.2.1 1:

> The function called at program startup is named `main`. The implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of `int` and with no parameters: … or with two parameters (referred to here as `argc` and `argv`, though any names may be used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared): …

Although that text restricts the declaration of `main`, it seems to me that it could be interpreted as referring to the `main` with external linkage, not to any routine that happens to be declared `main`. Nonetheless, it is generally bad practice to reuse well-known special-purpose names for other purposes.